# Upload de arquivo não funciona em hospedagem Locaweb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Localmente eu consigo efetuar o upload de arquivo e salvar tranquilamente em uma pasta utilizando o seguinte código

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CriarProduto(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   Produto produto = new Produto();
   ProdutoService prod = new ProdutoService();
   //Pego algumas infos do form e gravo o produto
   prod.Criar(produto);

  //Aqui começa a logica de upload da imagem
   var fileName = "";

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 1000000)
            {
                fileName = "produto" + produto.ProdutoId.ToString() + ".png";
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
  produto.Foto = fileName;
  prod.Atualizar(produto);

  return RedirectToAction("Produtos"); 
}
```

View:

```
// Parte do código - upload do arquivo
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
          <label class="control-label input-sm">Foto do produto</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Dessa maneira eu consigo gravar corretamente o arquivo na pasta que indiquei e no banco de dados gravo o nome do arquivo que especifiquei.

Acontece que quando hospedo na Locaweb nada disso funciona. Ele está gravando no banco de dados o nome da foto vazio, ou seja, ele nem se quer entra no `if` para gravar a imagem. E ele grava o produto tranquilamente no banco de dados, só não manda a foto e o nome no campo `Foto`.

Preciso subir alguma DLL a mais para a hospedagem?

Comment: Rafael, já passei por este problema. Entrei em contato com a LocaWeb e eles resolveram. Aqui no meu caso o problema era de permissões, aí foram eles que habilitaram as permissões.

Comment: Pior que eu liguei lá e o atendente não sabia resolver meu problema. Vou tentar mais uma vez.

Comment: Também me deparei com esse problema e obtive a solução da mesma forma que o Diego falou. Porém o meu upload funciona apenas em produção. Via localhost não consigo subir nenhum arquivo no FTP da LocaWeb

Comment: Aqui dava esse erro @RafaelMoura: "Access to the path 'caminho' is denied."

Comment: Consegui! Era isso mesmo, problema de permissão!

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar meu comentário como resposta. Assim se outro usuário estiver com este problema, poderá ajudar.

Entre em contato com a LocaWeb são eles que cuidam desses privilégios. O problema é de permissões, aí são eles que habilitam.

Pelo menos no meu caso, foi resolvido desta forma.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo indica que o que esta acontecendo é que você não tem permissão pra gravar no diretorio,
verifique com a empresa que te presta o serviço de hospedagem se você tem esse privilegio não é porque seu site ta hospedado que você tem os direitos de gravar informações no servidor.